# How long after a question is posted is it acceptable to reply?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

For example, if I see something that's helpful that I would like to follow up with a question, but the post is a year old.

How long ago is too long?

Does this matter, or is it frowned on?

---

EDIT - I am referring to commenting on existing questions or answers

Comment: _"... or is it frowned on?"_ I have a necromancer badge ;-) ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer

Comment: I posted my highest-voted answer on SO on a five-year-old question.

Comment: @ntoskrnl in spite of it, fewer people see the answer to the old question. OP should be aware that, no one reads his response. Especially when question has high up-vote answers.

Comment: No, you cannot *reply with a question*. You can ask for clarification with a comment to the question, or you can post an answer to the question. There's no *reply with a question*. You also can't *follow up with a question*, because that would be either a comment to the original question asking for clarification or a totally new question on it's own and should be placed in a separate post.

Comment: @KenWhite It would be in the same manner that you're posting on this -> but with a question. So someone would have posted an answer, and I would comment upon that answer with a question as it didn't provide enough information for me even though the OP was satisfied. Perhaps it's better to just make a new post and have a bunch of "this was already posted" comments, I'm not sure, hence this post.

Comment: That's not "reply with a question", then. It's "comment asking for more information", which means something differently.

Comment: @KenWhite yeah, but it's still a question in the sense I'm asking someone about something, I'm 'questioning' them. But I see how it's different to a question on a different topic or so on

Comment: You're splitting hairs. You're *posting a comment asking for additional information or clarification (that may include a question mark)*. Questions here have specific meaning: They're the main post at the top of the page that people then post answers to (in the area marked *Your Answer* in the lower half of the page. See the difference? *Question*: Big post at top. *Answer*: Bigger post(s) at bottom with the heading over them that says *X Answers*, just like the *2 Answers* that appear below left of this comment. *Comment*: The little box below a question or answer that you use to request info

Comment: @KenWhite And you're not? You really think that whole paragraph is needed? Question (within SO) is the OP follow ups are comments, done.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This assumes by "*reply*", you are referring to commenting on existing questions or answers.

If your question is requesting clarification *on the post* in its current form, you may reply with comments whenever you please.  I regularly get notifications of comments on answers several years old, requesting clarification updates etc.  This is often really helpful, because it can uncover issues with old answers in need of updates due to obsolete technologies, changes in best practices, etc.

If your comment is to ask *a different question* related to the the post, don't do it, regardless of the timeframe. That is more appropriately asked as an entirely new question.

If you are referring to *answering* old questions, that is always acceptable as long as you

1. actually *answer* the question, rather than request clarifications in the answers area (seeing that you don't yet have full commenting privileges at 50rep)
2. you provide some new insight to the question, rather than repeating what's already present in older answers.

Comment: Cheers - the odds are is that I would be asking the person who had answered for more clarification about what they meant, even though the OP may have been satisfied with the response. Is this 'bad form'? It feels a bit 'jumping on the band wagon' rather than making my own post, but then if it's relating perhaps it's not necessary to make a new post for it? Thanks !

Comment: @user3130747 It is perfectly ok if you ask for clarification as a **comment** under the respective post. But if you post it as an *answer* (*since you don't seem to have enough rep to comment*) then it is *not ok*.

Comment: @user3130747 It's totally okay to comment on an answer asking for clarification. Some users may not respond, if they've become inactive or just not interested in engaging on it, but one thing not always obvious to new users is that questions and answers only help the OP in the short timeframe after asking. They are meant to live on the site for the long term and continue to help future readers, so if clarification is needed, it is best asked for so that it can be incorporated into the answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski cheers. Sometimes there's already a post but it hasn't explained things fully enough for me (there might be shorthand or concepts in there I'm unfamiliar with) and posting a new one get's a load of shirty 'someones already posted this question' responses. I see what you're saying though, cheers

Comment: @user3130747 Right - I don't advocate posting a new question unless it is truly distinct from the old one, and in the new question, you specifically reference the old one and how it doesn't meet your needs, and how your needs specifically differ.  When you have enough reputation, there is also [the bounty system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) where you can offer up points to get fresh new answers on an old question (or a new one). This gathers a lot of attention and will lead to new answers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'd mention the bounty system on the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Some time ago on some forum there was a question:

> What does it mean when the second line on pregnancy test is only slightly visible?

When such question is one year old, you may assume that this woman already knows the answer and doesn't need it from you. But still, such answer may be useful for others that will search for such a question and will find such a thread.

It is similarily on Stack Overflow. When there is a one-year-old unanswered question, then probably OP doesn't need an answer anymore (especially when this is a homework question). But still, answering such a question has sense. All you have to do is to prepare a good answer. You can concentrate on every detail of it. You don't have to hurry. If no one answered for one year, there is little risk that someone will answer in an hour.

OP probably doesn't need your answer, so there is a big risk that they will simply ignore your answer. There is also a risk that not many people will see it at all. But it is rather long time investment. Maybe after half a year (or 20 years), someone will search for a similar question and will find your answer, and you will get your reward.

I have answered maybe 20 old questions and haven't received any response for over half of them.

Comment: I'm not bothered about points / rep etc, just wondering what best practice was :)

Comment: One of differences of StackOverflow from forums is that StackOverflow is more oriented towards helping other users in addition to the original question poster.